# How to recognize a QR Code in a Image

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-8.1, qr-code, scanning

While Scanning a QR code with Windows phone 8.1, along the QR code some more objects present in the preview. So, how to remove the unwanted objects from the image like cropping the QR code alone?

[image: Captured Image with QR Code]

I need to crop the QR code alone and i have scan it.

Thanks

Comment: The title is confusing, I think you don't want to recognize the QR code but just to segment it, isn't it ?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to decode QR code by yourself?
Otherwise you can use ZXing.Net.  Here is an [examples](https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#trunk/Clients/WindowsPhone8Demo/WindowsPhone8Demo.csproj).

Comment: The first sentence should probably be a comment and the linked example is very lengthy and difficult to find the important parts.